# Problem with else (program jump to else if there is no reason to do that)

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

So I'm practicing writing simple Java programs. I made one to change binary numbers to decimal. In last loop below all `if(){}`'s my program jumps to else without reason to do so. I've changed this last else to another if statement and program is running properly. But I wonder HOW it is possible that the first program is jumping to else. What property of if-else statements is making that?

Here is the code and outputs of both programs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumberToBinary1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Put binary number: ");
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String container = sn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(binaryToNumber(container));
   }

    private static double binaryToNumber(String container) {
        int numberLength = container.length();
        double result = 0;
        double power = 0;

        for (int i = numberLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char a = container.charAt(i);
            int x =a;
            if (x == 49) {                          //if digit from binary number is 1 add 2^(number of power) to result
                result += java.lang.Math.pow(2d, power);
                power++;
            }
            if (x==48) {                            //if digit from binary number is 0, just skip to next power of 2
                power++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("issue with "+(i+1)+ " number"); //else give error with i+1th digit
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Put binary number: 
10110105
issue with 8 digit
issue with 6 digit
issue with 4 digit
issue with 3 digit
issue with 1 digit
90.0
```

#### AND SECOND:

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberToBinary1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Put binary number: ");
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String container = sn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(binaryToNumber(container));
    }


    private static double binaryToNumber(String container) {
        int numberLength = container.length();
        double result = 0;
        double power = 0;

        for (int i = numberLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char a = container.charAt(i);
            int x =a;
            if (x == 49) {                                  //if digit from binary number is 1 add 2^(number of power) to result
                result += java.lang.Math.pow(2d, power);
                power++;
            }
            if (x==48){                                     //if digit from binary number is 0, just skip to next power of 2
                power++;
            }
            if(x!=49 && x!=48) {System.out.println("issue with "+(i+1)+" digit"); //if digit from binary number is not 1 or 0 -> give error
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Put binary number: 
10110105
issue with 8 digit
90.0
```

Comment: The first program will go to the else for all numbers except 48 because that is what you told it to do. "if 48, then increment power, else print 'Issue with...'" You probably meant to use an if/else if/else instead.

Comment: Thanks i realized that u need to do IF ELSE every time after first IF.

Comment: Note: you can use `'0'` instead of `48` ... same for `'1'`... actually you could have done `if (ch == '1')` - just for better reading

Answer (score 0):

Because in your first program else belongs only to second if statement, that's mean all values that not pass this if will go to else. In your second program you modified your statement. You can also try to modify your first program to this, it should give you the same result:

```
private static double binaryToNumber(String container) {
    int numberLength = container.length();
    double result = 0;
    double power = 0;

    for (int i = numberLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char a = container.charAt(i);
        int x =a;
        if (x == 49) {                          //if digit from binary number is 1 add 2^(number of power) to result
            result += java.lang.Math.pow(2d, power);
            power++;
        } else if (x==48) {                            //if digit from binary number is 0, just skip to next power of 2
            power++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("issue with "+(i+1)+ " number"); //else give error with i+1th digit
        }
    } return result;
}
```

Comment: The use of good code style/formatting helps make this type of error more visible.  @amedv's code is easy to see if/elseif/else are all together and I think it would be noticeable if the first 'else' were missing.